# How do I display the Time, Date IP and URL on a page? UPDATED - 25.02.2015

Tags: javascript, html, url, ip

How do I display the Time and Date on the page of a specific Time Zone, display the IP address of the Computer that is accessing the page and display the URL the page is located on.

Thank in advance,

Jim

NOTE: Is this what the coding goes in?

```
<script>
  coding
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the URL: `window.location.toString()`. You can't get the IP address in native JavaScript. To get the time, go ahead and execute, `Date()`

```
var url = window.location.toString();
var time = Date();

alert(url);
alert(time);
```

Comment: SO could i get the IP some other way?

Comment: Thanks for the other stuff

Comment: Is this what is should look like?

<script>
window.location.toString()
Date()
</script>

Comment: @Tropilac update your code instead of putting in that comment ^^

Comment: It still doesnt seem to do anthing... How exactly do I type it? (I am a bit of a noob)

Comment: type it in exactly how it looks in this answer. I edited it again.

Comment: This works, thank you. (Is is possible to get the IP?)